# How to properly embed MJPEG video in Angular app - Chrome, Edge, other browsers

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge, mjpeg

Hello StackOverflow proffesionals!

At first - I'm not a programmer, so please be kind to me :-)

I have an application written in Angular - JavaScript. I have webserver(Nginx) which is streaming webcam video as MJPEG stream at address ../webcam . What I need is embed somelike the MJPEG stream into a page in my application, for viewing to users. When I add a simple ../webcam clickable link, video is playing only in some of the browsers, but for example Edge asks for saving the file, it do not not playback the video. I've even tried to do an iframe (actual code), but still the same - mobile Edge asks where to save the file :-(

Is there any option how to embed the MJPEG stream into a page, so Edge will not ask for download/save, but will play the video stream?

The page is now this code:
https://vicon-security.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/210734683-How-can-I-re-stream-MJPEG-from-my-camera-to-my-website-

Code of the whole application on GitHub:
https://github.com/romanicak/growduino-client

Answer (score 0):

Try to use video tag instead of Iframe. It may help you to solve the issue.

```html
<video data-title="Live stream">
<source type="application/x-mpegurl"
        src="your URL goes here...">
   </video>
```

Make a test with code and let us know about your testing result.

Comment: Not working at all. Page now looks like: `<html>
<head>
    <title>Growroom WebCam</title>
</head>

<body>
<video data-title="Live stream">
    <source type="application/x-mpegurl"
            src="../webcam">
</video>
</body>`

Comment: Here, i want to confirm with you that are you making a test on mobile Edge? Can you share the URL for live streaming? I can try to make a test and check whether that format is supported or not on mobile. Also let us know, which device and which platform you are using for making a test. It can help us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hello Deepak, yes, I'm testing it on a Lumia 950XL Win10 mobile Edge. Live URL straight to video is https://185.47.222.180/webcam , but You have to be logged in into https://185.47.222.180 - username/pass is grdw/grdw .